# How to create the crystal report dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
CrystalReport3 cr = new CrystalReport3();
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

cr.Load(@"CrystalReport3.rpt");

cr.Database.Tables["ItemDetails"].SetDataSource(dt1);
crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cr;
cryRpt = (ReportDocument)crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource;
```

Comment: Can you please add more details to question that what you want and where did you stuck now

Comment: actually in dt1 datatable i will get values like tableno,itemname,categoryname and price ...but i want create crystal report for each table ..